# Libgdx Disable Vsync for Android Instead of Desktop

Tags: android, libgdx, vsync

Hi I want to disable or enable vsync for my game and I found this link
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Fullscreen-&-vsync

So I was able to change the setting for the desktop version of my app. My question is does this also change things for when I run it on android? It doesn't seem to work as far as I can tell and In the androidlauncher instead of a LwjglApplicationConfiguration for config it has AndroidApplicationConfiguration.

So is there anyway to do this for android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vsync cannot be disabled on mobile devices in libgdx. I think Android is set up to automatically perform back buffer management for GLSurfaceViews, so this can only be managed on the device or ROM level.